# Running threads slowly reducing in number

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, asynchronous

I have a process that I want to run concurrently.  The process requests and processes a json file with `HttpClient`.

It starts out working really fast and then gradually slows down.  I save all spawned tasks to a `List<Task>`.  If I set a break point right after execution starts there are around 98 tasks in the task list.  After 5-10 minutes the processing is going really slow, when I set a breakpoint there are only around 60 tasks running but the processing is now incredibly slow.  Maybe 10-20% of initial speed.

RAM usage looks fine.  At the start my CPU is running at around 90% but after 5-10 mins it drops to 50% and the number of records being processed is very low.

I am using a `SemaphoreSlim` to control how many processes are running.

```
static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(100, 100);
```

This is how I am spawning the tasks.  I am reading from a very large file (millions of records) so this while loop is going to need to run indefinitely withut slowing down.

```
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
int currentRow = 0;

using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(processPath + fileName))
{
    string dataLine;
    while ((dataLine = sReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

        taskList.RemoveAll(x => x.IsCompleted);

        semaphore.Wait();
        Interlocked.Increment(ref currentRow);

        string domain = dataLine.Split(',')[0];
        int row = currentRow;

        taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => GetArchiveCounts(domain, row, token)));

        tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
    }
}
Task.WhenAll(taskList).Wait();
```

I am doing the IO in `GetArchiveCounts()` method.  I am passing a cancellation token and setting that to auto cancel after 180 seconds to try to avoid any threads getting locked out permanently and causing slow downs.  When I set my breakpoints I don't see any tasks with a status of cancelled.

I am releasing the semaphore inside the `GetArchiveCounts()` method:

```
public static async Task GetArchiveCounts(string domain, int row, CancellationToken token)
{
    bool done = false;

    while (token.IsCancellationRequested == false && done == false)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl, token);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // omitted code, I just process result here
            }
        }
        done = true;
    }
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

The cancellation pattern I am using here doesn't feel right and I am guessing it might be the cause of my problem but I am not sure.  I am having difficulty figuring out whats going on as I am not getting any errors to go on.  I think it should be possible to maintain the speed I get on the first few hundred processed records indefinitely but I can't figure out what in my code is to blame.

Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Comment: Do you do any exception handling you left out here for brevity? I recommend to use the `try{}finally{ semphore.Release(); }` pattern.

Comment: Actually I haven't got that in there.  If an exception occurred wouldn't it completely stop execution and cause exception to be raised in parent thread?

Comment: _" If an exception occurred wouldn't it completely stop execution and cause exception to be raised in parent thread?"_ - Test it. Just add a `throw new Exception()` ... But even if it would bubble up, the release wouldn't be executed.

Comment: ahh, that was unexpected.  It is not reporting the exception!  I guess this is most likely issue.  I will add try catch finally and re-test.  Thanks

Comment: For millions of rows, `using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))` might be what kills you.

Comment: See the docs and google "you are using httpclient wrong", see what `netstat` can tell you.

Comment: Each client needs a different proxy so I did it like this to make it possible to rotate the proxies.  I dont think I can re-use a httpclient and change it's proxy

Comment: So you have millions of proxies... ?

Comment: But you could make a lookup / cache of HttpClients per proxy. What Henk is going for is that your perceived slow down probably is caused by a shortage of available ports. When they are given back, it still needs some time for them to become available again. So an easy first improvement would be to inject one instance of HttpClient into the Method instead of creating them Millions of times.

Comment: I see your point.  I am only using 100 proxies so I could instantiate 100 and then figure out a way to assign threads to the same ones.  I guess I can't be lazy here.  I'll give it a go thanks for help :)